# New Access & Refresh Tokens not generating after refresh token after expiration time

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

When the user is logged in then the new refresh and access tokens are generated which are stored in the local storage using reactjs. When the access token is expired then no new access token is created and stored in the local storage and same goes for refresh token.

settings.py

```js
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'main',
    'ecom',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    '127.0.0.1',
    # ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'shopy.urls'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'main.custom_authenticators.CustomAuthentication',
      ],
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
     'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(seconds=5),
     'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(seconds=5),
     'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
     'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
     'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
     'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
}
```

main/custom_authenticators.py

```js
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication

class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return None
        return super().authenticate(request)
```

interceptors/axios.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  
  if (access_token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
  }

  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, async function (error) {
  const originalRequest = error.config;

  if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;

    const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

    if (refresh_token) {
      try {
        const { exp } = jwt_decode(refresh_token);
        const expirationTime = dayjs.unix(exp);

        if (expirationTime.diff(dayjs()) > 1) {
          const response = await axios.post('/token/refresh/', {
            refresh: refresh_token
          });

          localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);

          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`;

          return axios(originalRequest);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default axios;
```